# Looking for a single word for 'almost real in appearance'

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a single word for describing dolls that looks like real human beings.

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests." If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you include a bit of background and research into the question, instead of simply asking *"I'm trying to think of a word..."* See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Answer (score 14):

**Lifelike** would seem to be the obvious choice.

http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lifelike

Answer (score 8):

**Verisimilitude** captures for 'close to real'.

Comment: Verisimilar-  as an adjective

Comment: @Ritu how about 'verisimilitudinous'?

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for an adjective which means *apparently (but not actually) real*, try **virtual**. Using the adjective form, you could say the dolls are ***virtually*** human.[¹](http://wordnetweb.princeton.edu/perl/webwn?s=virtually)

Answer (score 3):

Verisimilitude is a noun. Verisimilar is appropriate but sounds like two words.

Would ***realistic*** fit the bill?

Other alternatives are naturalistic, graphic, vivid, convincing, compelling

The last word is my preferred option

Answer (score 2):

If you want to say that they look like humans, try *[humanoid.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/humanoid)*

Comment: This seems to me to imply human shape, but not almost real in appearance as the OP requested.

Comment: @MetaEd The body of the question says that the dolls look like humans, so this answer applies to those. Downvote if you like, but I think it applies.

Comment: Not a downvote; it's helpful, as you say, but I do think it misses the point. The OP requsted a word for "almost real in appearance".

Comment: @MetaEd By that logic, Irene's answer should also be downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

Dolls of human size which are used for showing clothes in shop windows are called **mannequins**.

Answer (score 0):

It may be obvious, it may be literal and it may be hyphenated but how about:

> The dolls were so *human-like*